# DNS through an AWS Direct Connect

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services

I have an AWS Direct Connect to a private network that has no Internet connection. It will be used to download from a S3 bucket. Is there a way I can resolve DNS through the Direct Connect without having to build a DNS resolver in a VPC?

[Network Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXyhR.png)

Comment: Which side has no internet connection? The AWS or the on-prem? A simple network diagram may help too...

Comment: Diagram added, the on-prem has no internet. Essentially, if I have a URL for an S3 bucket, I need a way to resolve that and then access the bucket though the direct connect

Answer (score 0):

One way is indeed the *Route53 Resolver* but that may be too expensive for your needs.

The alternative is to *spin up a tiny EC2 instance*, e.g. `t3a.nano` and install `bind`, `knot`, `dnsmasq` or some other DNS software. You can also use the same instance as a HTTP/HTTPS proxy (`squid`) for giving the on-prem computers outside access, optionally controlled by a proxy whitelist.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: We tend to use Route53 Resolver for enterprise customers where reliability is more important than price, or a very small instance running one of those pieces of software you mentioned where cost is the priority or high availability isn't important. In most cases you can use DNS on the client side, but the client side having DirectConnect but not internet is an unusual configuration.